# TASK RECORDS THAT DO NOT APPEAR IN REPORTS AND QUERRY (The requested resource does not exist)

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning, soql

When creating a report of opportunities with tasks, I noticed that there were some records of tasks that should be showing up and weren't.
When I went to analyze these tasks, I saw that the task history appears to be zero and when trying to query the record using the Salesforce Inspector puglin, it throws the error:
*"Error retrieving record: NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist"*

These records also do not appear in the query.

(these tasks that do not appear are from the beginning of 2022, and it is as completed,
there are older records (2021/2020) that have a history of tasks and appear in the report normally)

[image]

**Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this?**

I'm thinking of filling in these values for these tasks in a spreadsheet and inserting them again to appear in the user's report... I don't know if there's any way to "recover" these records.

Comment: are these archived activities by chance?

Comment: Hii,
How are they archived? Can activity records be archived in some configuration and why does this error appear?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385669&type=1